# How to save configuration settings for my NodeJs CLI app?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I'm crafting a nodejs application as a cli tool. I'm using `yargs` to define my commands and I'm using the `.config()` method to load default configuration settings from a .config or config.json file, like so:

```
const findUp = require('find-up')
const fs = require('fs')
const yargs = require('yargs');

const configPath = findUp.sync(['.config', 'config.json']);
const config = configPath ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath)) : {};

yargs
    .command( require('./command/command-name'))
    .option( .... )
    .config( config )
    .argv
```

I would like to create a command that I can use to configure my .config file. Something like:

```
my-tool configure --defaults key1=<value> key2=<value>
```

Is there an npm package available to do this, or would I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled my own.

```
# configure.js
const findUp = require('find-up')
const fs = require('fs')

exports.command = 'configure'
exports.desc    = 'Set or view your configuration'
exports.builder = {
    'defaults': {
        desc: 'set configuration values',
        type: 'array',
        group: 'Parameters:'

    }
}
exports.handler = function (argv) {

    const configPath = findUp.sync(['.config', 'config.json']);
    const config = configPath ? JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath)) : {};

    if (argv.defaults) {
        argv.defaults.map( arg => {
            var args = arg.split('=');
            if (args[1]) {
                config[args[0]] = args[1];
            } else {
                delete config[args[0]];
            }            
        })

        var file = configPath ? configPath : "./.config";
        fs.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log( JSON.stringify(config, null, 2));
    }
}
```